# Is this a valid log operation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I saw this and this 1st step looked fishy....
Bringing the 4 inside the ()'s....Is that valid?
That last step also looks weird.  the square just goes away?

$$4(\log_b3)^2=(\log_b3^4)^2=(log_b81)^2=(log_b9^2)^2=(log_b9)^2$$

I would think:
$$4(\log_b3)^2=4(\log_b3)(\log_b3)=(\log_b3^4)(\log_b3) $$

Alternatively,
$$(\log_b3^4)^2=(\log_b3^4)(\log_b3^4)=4(\log_b3)4(\log_b3)= 16(\log_b3) \neq 4(\log_b3)^2$$

Right ?

Comment: what's the relationship between $b$ and $x$? are you solving for $x$ in terms of $b$?

Comment: I fixed the typo where I accidentally used $log_x$ instead of $log_b$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is incorrect as you say. It must be:

$$4(\log_b3)^2=(2\log_b3)^2=(\log_b9)^2$$

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: @Alizter I don't see why not, given the question.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no specified relationship between $b$  ($b>0, b\not=1$) and $x$ ($x>0, x\not=1$), I'll find the relationship that makes the equality true.

$$4(\log_b3)^2=(\log_x3^4)^2$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  \quad (2\log_b3)^2 = (\log_x3^4)^2$$

$$  \Leftrightarrow  \quad \pm \log_b3 = 2\log_x3$$

$$  \Leftrightarrow  \quad \pm 2\ln b = \ln x$$

$$  \Leftrightarrow  \quad x = {\rm e}^{\pm 2\ln b} = b^{\pm 2}$$

If $$  x \not= b^{\pm 2},$$

then the "fishiness" holds, that is, we'll have

$$4(\log_b3)^2 \not= (\log_x3^4)^2.$$

**Edit:**

If $x$ is equal to $b$ (as per ***edited*** question), as $b$ is positive and cannot be $1$ (so $b\not= b^{\pm 2}$), then the equality fails, that is, we ***always*** have:

$$4(\log_b3)^2 \not= (\log_b3^4)^2.$$

Comment: I fixed the typo where I accidentally used $log_x$ instead of $log_b$

Comment: Ok. If $x$ is equal to $b$, as $b$ canot be $1$, then the equality fails, as shown in my answer.